# Docker run works but Docker compose up

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

so I have this project which has frontend in angular and backend in PHP Symfony also using mongodb as database.

The problem is when I run `docker compose up` and then try to access `localhost:4200` or `localhost:80` angular project does not show up. Unlike when I run the frontend image like this `docker run -p 4200:4200 orderup_frontend` then it runs on `localhost:80`

Let me know where is the issue or what am I missing.

Docker compose yaml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://database/orderup
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - orderup:/data/database

volumes:
  orderup:
```

Dockerfile for frontend ( angular ):

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:18-alpine as builder


WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# Use a smaller image as a base for the final image
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the built Angular application from the builder stage to the final image
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 4200
EXPOSE 4200
```

Dockerfile for backend (PHP Symfony ):

```
FROM php:8.0.3-fpm

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install git zip libpq-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN curl -sL https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir /usr/bin --filename composer

RUN pecl install xdebug

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```